# jQuery Countdown IE refresh issue

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am using the jQuery countdown plugin (http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) and using the serverTime feature:

```
function serverTime() {
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax({url: 'cgi/server-time.php', 
    async: false, dataType: 'text', 
    success: function(text) { 
        time = new Date(text); 
    }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
        time = new Date();
    }}); 
    return time; 
 }
```

Now when I hit refresh, Firefox is correct however IE resets the clock to a set time which is completely incorrect i.e. Firefox says 44 min remaining, IE says 1 hour, 36 min remaining.

If I set async to true then it is using the local machine time which could also be incorrect.

server-time.php

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1 
header("Expires: Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return time from that function if async is true.  The ajax call is asynchronous.  It has NOT completed the ajax call when the serverTime function returns.  If you want to use the returned time, you have to call the function that's going to use it from the success function.  This is a very common mistake - I've probably written about it 10-15 times in the last couple weeks.

If async is false, then this should work unless the browser is caching your php file, though your page will lock up during the ajax call until it returns.

If you want to make 100% sure that your ajax call never returns a cached result, then append a random query string to it like this so it's always a unique URL:

```
cgi/server-time.php?random=83987569284
```

You can create a random number like this:

```
var php = "cgi/server-time.php?random=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000);
```

I would recommend using the async ajax call, adding the random number generation to the URL and then to make the async work, you can't use the return value from serverTime, but rather have to continue your flow of control by calling a function from the success handler.